# Freeradius with google protobuf

Tags: protocol-buffers, radius, freeradius

I want to use google protobuf with freeradius. The idea that Freeradius should able to encode/decode send/receive RADIUS message.

I found one link but doesn't know how to make or install it. As not much mentioned in README file.

https://github.com/rssh/rlm_protobuf/tree/freeradius-2.1.x

Answer (score 0):

It required to run ./configure file to make MAKE file then package can be bulid and installed.